# Hacer una lista de dos columnas sql server

Tags: sql-server

Tengo que hacer una sola lista de todos los usuarios y presentarlos en una sola columna, cuando intento usar la función concat() une el usuario 1 y el 2
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

select concat(id_usr1, id_usr2) as todos from usrs

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Me podrían ayudar a que no se una el usr1 y el usr2 si no que se muestren separados, gracias

El resultado que quiero tener es que se muestren los 54 registros así como lo mostré en excel
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que se muestren separados...de qué forma?, puedes agregar el resultado que quieres?

Comment: @Lamak ya agregue el resultado que quiero obtener espero explicarme

Comment: entonces quieres los resultados así tal cual?, con los usuarios repetidos?

Comment: Exactamente @Lamak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Para evitar leer la tabla 2 veces, se puede usar la operación `APPLY`. Con eso podemos decirle que lo ponga en dos filas con `UNION ALL` o con el generador de tablas `VALUES`. Ejemplos:

```
SELECT id_usr AS todos 
FROM usrs
CROSS APPLY ( SELECT id_usr1 AS id_usr 
            UNION ALL
            SELECT id_usr2) x
WHERE id_usr IS NOT NULL;

SELECT id_usr AS todos 
FROM usrs
CROSS APPLY ( VALUES( id_usr1), 
                    ( id_usr2)) x(id_usr)
WHERE id_usr IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Queda perfecta solo le agrgaría un WHERE para que quite los NULL @Luis Cazares

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar el **operador de conjuntos union all**:

```
select id_usr1
from usrs
union all
select id_usr2
from usrs;
```

De esta forma ambas columnas quedarán unidas en una sola. El **operador union all** toma los resultados devueltos por la primera consulta y los une a los resultados obtenidos en la segunda consulta, obteniendo como resultado la unión de ambas consultas. **Este operador no elimina duplicados**, para eliminar duplicados puedes usar el **operador union**.

**Actualización**:

Para eliminar los nulos del resultado final podrías hacer:

```
select *
from
(
 select id_usr1 as usuario
 from usrs
 union all
 select id_usr2 as usuario
 from usrs
) T
where T.usuario is not null;
```

Sobre la consulta que hace la unión aplicas una consulta más general y usando la **claúsula where** obtienes las filas que no son nulas.

Comment: ojo que `UNION ALL` tampoco quita los `NULL`s, y el op no muestra null dentro del resultado esperado

Comment: Me funciono perfectamente, ese era el resultado que quería, y en efecto elimina los nulos de esa forma, te agradezco @Lamak

Comment: @ZuleikaCastrejon no fue  Lamak quien te respondio sino japv, si la respuesta te fue util te agradeceria que la marcaras como aceptada, gracias

Comment: Lo siento me confundí, me fue muy útil, y ya la marque como aceptada @Japv

Comment: @Lamak gracias por la aclaracion